# Eigen template library Random() method algorithm

Tags: c++, random, eigen

does anyone know, which algorithm the Eigen library for C++ uses in the method Random():

[eigen - random() doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a8e759dafdd9ecc446d397b7f5435f60a)

?

If eigen passes this decision on to the compiler (using its standard method to create pseudo random numbers), than I would like to know which algorithm g++ (gcc49 4.9.2_2) uses as default.

Any helpful hint is much appreciated.

Comment: A quick grep through the Eigen sources seems to suggest it's just calling rand(), so you'll need to look your compiler library.

Answer (score 3):

As Paul R pointed out, the default is to just call `rand`. If you look in Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h you'll find the default:

```
template<typename Scalar>
struct random_default_impl<Scalar, false, false>
{
  static inline Scalar run(const Scalar& x, const Scalar& y)
  {
    return x + (y-x) * Scalar(std::rand()) / Scalar(RAND_MAX);
  }
  static inline Scalar run()
  {
    return run(Scalar(NumTraits<Scalar>::IsSigned ? -1 : 0), Scalar(1));
  }
};
```

or variants on the theme (for different variable types).